# How to add new user to hyperledger fabric network using rest api

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have issued new participant id using Post operation of /system/identities/issue and got the card file having connection json and enrollment id and secret. Now how to generate certificate using that enrollment id and secret using the already created rest api by comopser-rest-server.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out, the Identity Issue results in a .card file (an archive containing the Connection, enrollment ID and Secret)  The Secret is a **one time secret** and the first time the card is used the Certificates are downloaded and stored locally.  After this the Secret is not valid.  This works the same way for CLI, Playground and REST API.

For CLI and Playground the cards (and certificates) are stored in under the home directory of the logged in user `~/.composer/` .

For the REST server, you need to run the REST server in Multiuser mode and then there are some new endpoints under /wallet e.g. /wallet/import.  The REST server stores the Cards (and certificates) in these Wallets.  This is described in this document [REST Server Multiuser](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html).

A couple of additional notes: To run in Multiuser mode you also need to enable Authentication for the REST Server.  When you stop the REST server the Wallets will be lost unless you persist a datastore for the REST server.

This parent doc has all the information for the REST server. [REST Server Parent Doc](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/integrating-index)